# Another question for Synth dataprep() Error unit.variable not found as numeric variable in foo

Tags: r, synth

I am using the `Synth` package to demonstrate the divergence in development between Djibouti and a synthetic model of Djibouti if it didn't have international intervention.

Despite several similar questions and attempts at the offered answers, I have still be struggling with the error:

```
unit.variable not found as numeric variable in foo
```

I have tried several different `dataprep()` strategies and still cannot run the code.

```r
ddSMI <- as.data.frame(ddSMI) %>%   
   mutate(LifeYrs = as.numeric(LifeYrs),
          PedYrs = as.numeric(PedYrs),
          Health.Index.Total = as.numeric(Health.Index.Total),
          Income.Index.Total = as.numeric(Income.Index.Total),
          SchoolMean = as.numeric(SchoolMean),
          Cno = as.numeric(Cno))
```

I am trying to produce a synthetic control model and have been using different iterations of this code. Though I have changed the class to numeric successfully, I still get the same error.
Here is the head of my data for  `reprex`

```
head(ddSMI)
# A tibble: 6 x 8
   Year   Cno Country PedYrs LifeYrs          
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>  <chr>            
1  2000     1 Algeria 6.31   69.5999999999999…
2  2001     1 Algeria 6.23   69.2             
3  2002     1 Algeria 6.28   69.5             
4  2003     1 Algeria 6.32   71.0999999999999…
5  2004     1 Algeria 6.36   71.4000000000000…
6  2005     1 Algeria 6.39   71.7             
# … with 3 more variables: SchoolMean <chr>,
#   Health Index Total <chr>,
#   Income Index Total <chr>
```

Please see the code below.

```
dataprep.out <- dataprep(foo = ddSMI,
                         predictors = c("LifeYrs", "PedYrs", "Health.Index.Total", "Income.Index.Total", "SchoolMean"),
                         predictors.op = "mean", # the operator
                         time.predictors.prior = 2007:2008, #the entire time frame from the #beginning to the end
                         special.predictors = list(
                           list("HDI Rank", 2000:2020, "mean"),
                           list("LifeYrs", seq(2007,2008,2), "mean"),
                           list("PedYrs", seq(2007,2008,2), "mean"),
                           list("Health Index Total", seq(2007, 2008, 2), "mean"),
                           list("Income Index Total", seq(2007,2008, 2), "mean"),
                           list("School Mean", seq(2007, 2008, 2), "mean")),
                         dependent = "HDI Rank", #dv
                         unit.variable = "Cno", #identifying unit numbers
                         unit.names.variable = "Country", #identifying unit names
                         time.variable = "Year", #time period
                         treatment.identifier = 5,#the treated case
                         controls.identifier = c(2:4, 6:15),#the control cases; all others #except number 5
                         time.optimize.ssr = 2007:2008,#the time-period over which to optimize
                         time.plot = 2000:2020)#the entire time period before/after the treatment
```

Here is a helpful resource on the Synth package which I used to help guide/ troubleshoot: ["Synth: An R Package for Synthetic Control Methodsin Comparative Case Studies"](http://web.stanford.edu/%7Ejhain/Paper/JSS2011.pdf)

My data is in the same format and yet...can't get it to run! It would be immensely appreciated if anyone can crack this!

Comment: I don't know the `synth` package but your error message says something about `unit.variable not found as numeric...` and the column `unit.variable` defined in your data.frame is a character var. Perhaps those things are linked?

Comment: Thank you @MartinGal! I prior to the posted code I actually cleaned the data to ensure that unit.variable is numeric `ddSMI <- as.data.frame(ddSMI) %>%
  mutate(LifeYrs = as.numeric(LifeYrs),
         PedYrs = as.numeric(PedYrs),
         Health.Index.Total = as.numeric(Health.Index.Total),
         Income.Index.Total = as.numeric(Income.Index.Total),
         SchoolMean = as.numeric(SchoolMean),
         Cno = as.numeric(Cno))` when I check it says `> class(ddSMI$Cno)
[1] "numeric"` ...so this is where I am stuck

Comment: Does `Cno` contain any `NA`'s?

Comment: thank you @MartinGal for continuing to help me with this! No, the `Cno` variable is just an identifier for each country so each observation for Ethiopia has a 1 in the `Cno` column, each observation of Zambia has a 12 in the `Cno` column, etc.

Comment: Since I'm not able to help you further, perhaps you can add some sample data to create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: thanks again @MartinGal for trying--I included some reprex, so hopefully that will help!

Answer (score 6):

I had a similar error, although it had nothing to do with the unit variable being numeric (it is basically the first error message in the code: see [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/Synth/src/R/dataprep.R)).

Make sure your object is a dataframe, and only a dataframe. I would recommend checking the data structure with the "synth.data" example that is provided with the package. Given your code is suggesting your object is also a tibble (tbl_df), this might be the reason for the error.

```
is.data.frame(synth.data)
[1] TRUE
class(synth.data)
[1] "data.frame"
```

```
is.data.frame(DATA)
[1] TRUE
class(DATA)
[1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
DATA <- as.data.frame(DATA)
class(DATA)
[1] "data.frame"
```