# unit.variable not found as numeric variable in foo Synth Package

Tags: data-preprocessing, synth

I am trying to run the Synthetic Control Method in R. I tried to prepare my data according to Abadie, Diamond and Hainmueller (2011) (https://www.jstatsoft.org/article/view/v042i13).
But when running the dataprep.out function I get the error message that my unit.variables are not nurmeric variables in foo. I don't understand the problem here because my table purely consists of numeric values. The table is also classified as a data.frame. I have attached some pictures to underline my problem. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated!

My code (https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BVYc.png)
My table (https://i.stack.imgur.com/TV1IC.png)

I have tried to reimport my data over and over again. But nothing seems to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and following the solution by Nick Bombaij in [Another question for Synth dataprep() Error unit.variable not found as numeric variable in foo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67694975/another-question-for-synth-dataprep-error-unit-variable-not-found-as-numeric-v) worked for me. That is using the as.data.frame command to transform my data to be in the class of data.frame only. Then class(data) should gives answer
"data.frame"
instead of
"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"